# Label are not shown in pdf saved from python plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot in python and I should use a large font for the figure. However, when I save the figure in pdf format, it does not show the label. Could you please help me with that? Here is a code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lw         = 2.5
lwn        = 1.7
beingsaved = plt.figure()
fnt_size   = 35
fnt_size   = 35
fnt_sizexx   = 35
csfont     = {'fontname':"Times New Roman", 'size': fnt_size}
csfontxx    = {'fontname':"Times New Roman", 'size': fnt_sizexx}
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman"
plt.rcParams["axes.linewidth"]  = 0.5        

b= [16.72,22.27,16.24,13.69,16.64,33.46,10,22.11,35.79,32.53,25.,34,48.66,30.30,41.73]
a = [8.4, 6.6, 5.2, 4.0, 4.9, 10.9, 5.6, 5.2, 10.1, 7.1, 5.2, 9.1, 27.7, 6.5, 10.0]

plt.figure(figsize=(14,7.2))  

plt.plot(b,'-ob',linewidth=lw )


plt.xticks(rotation=90)

plt.xticks([0, 1,2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14], [f"{a[i]}" for i in range(15)])

plt.yticks([15,30,45], ["15", "30", "45"])

plt.xlabel('Percentage load (%)',**csfontxx)

plt.ylabel('Energy (%)',**csfont)

plt.xticks(**csfontxx) 

plt.yticks(**csfont)
plt.ylim(5, 50)
plt.xlim(0, 14)
plt.savefig('file.pdf', dpi=2000)
plt.show()
```

And here is the output in pdf format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX7IS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a mistake in line 29.

```
plt.xlabel('Percentage load (%)',**csfontx)
```

should be, I believe:

```
plt.xlabel('Percentage load (%)',**csfontxx)
```

Edit: please add this after line 14. It'll fix everything.

```
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I just edited that. But, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @sadcow Your font is too big. Reduce it to 25 or 20. I got the desired result.

Comment: Yes. I know that my font is big and I mentioned this in my question also! that I have to use a large font.

Comment: Hey I fixed your problem. Please use:

plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

Comment: @sadcow try it now. Keep the font same. It'll be fixed.